# Why can I not use :: after a list to append a string to it in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

So I assume my issue has to do with what is going on under the hood, but I don't understand why this doesn't works:

```
scala> b = b :: "apple";
<console>:8: error: value :: is not a member of java.lang.String
```

but this does:

```
scala> b = "apple" :: b;
b: List[java.lang.String] = List(apple, pear)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method names that end in `:` are right associative, so `b :: "apple"` tries to call the `::` method on a String, which doesn't exist.

The normal strategy for appending things if you must use a `List` is to add things to the beginning then `reverse` the result when you're done. But as Rex says, using a Vector might be better.

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks! I was wondering why it was giving me that string error, I assumed thats what it was doing. So the 2nd : in :: makes it right associative?

Answer (score 6):

`::` always joins a new item to the head of a list.  Adding an item to the end can be done, but it takes time proportional to the length of the list (since the entire list must not only be traversed but, actually, also rebuilt).

If you really must add a item to the end of a list, use `:+`:

```
List("pear","orange") :+ "apple"
```

Better yet, use `Vector` when you need to add to the end (it's much faster at double-ended additions):

```
Vector("grape","peach") :+ "apple"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to explicitly add `Nil` to the end of chain:

```
scala> val a = "apple"
a: java.lang.String = apple

scala> val b = "pear"
b: java.lang.String = pear

scala> a::b::Nil
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(apple, pear)
```

Comment: If you have a list `val xs = List(1,2,3)` to which you want to append, you would need the list append method `:::` for this technique: `xs ::: 4 :: Nil`.